# Does Jar file shrinker affect performance

Tags: java, file-structure, obfuscation, jit

I've heard [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)'s Jar shrinker affects the performance of you application. Is this true? And if so just how much slower does the Jar go shrinked compared to unshrinked?

Comment: Where have you heard that it slows down your application (please provide a link). A smaller jar normally leads to increased performance as there is less to load. And decompressing can be faster than loading a file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about the guessing of inner functionality of third party products.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, "shrinking" can only make an application load *faster*. Once loaded, there should be little or no difference in speed, though memory consumption can decrease.

Basically, the shrinker removes unused code, which reduces the amount of class-loading work the JVM has to do and the amount of memory taken up by that code.

Comment: "Basically, the shrinker removes unused code, which reduces the amount of class-loading work the JVM has to do". But no class will be loaded from the unused code, so how come this statement is true.

Comment: @SanjeevKumarDangi: I meant cases where unused *parts* of a class are removed, i.e. methods that are not called anywhere in the application. That makes the class smaller and thus less work for the classloader.